# Indendentation of Python Multi-line Comment

Tags: python, format, comments, standards, pep

In python, I have a short comment - using the `#` syntax - that I want to add to a statement. It isn't important enough to be a docstring; it's just a little reminder. 
The comment takes up two lines, which gives me a style decision:

```
Should I indent the second line of the comment to show that it is a continuation?
```

This is a relatively trivial issue, but I want to make sure my code is conformant to standard code styles. However, I could not find anything related to this by a google search.

Here's an example of not indenting:

```
# Idea 1 is a really good idea,
# uhoh I ran out of space so
# I'm using multiple lines.
# Idea 2 is also a really good
# idea, and I also ran out of
# space for this one.
```

Here's an example of indenting one space:

```
# Idea 1 is a really good idea,
#  uhoh I ran out of space so
#  I'm using multiple lines.
# Idea 2 is also a really good
#  idea, and I also ran out of
#  space for this one.
```

And finally, here's an example of indenting a tab:

```
# Idea 1 is a really good idea,
#     uhoh I ran out of space so
#     I'm using multiple lines.
# Idea 2 is also a really good
#     idea, and I also ran out of
#     space for this one.
```

Which one is the right style? Is there an official source that says? What do you or others you know prefer to use?

Comment: I have never seen anyone indent comments like that. If you want to separate two multi-line comments, you can use a blank line.

Comment: Do whatever as long as it's readable. If this was a significant issue, there'd be a rule for it in one of the popular linters

Comment: [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#comments) doesn't apply *much* formatting to comments, and nothing applicable to the comments in this question.

Comment: Multi-line comments tend to be used with triple quotes such as docstrings. But as in previous comment do whatever you want as long as you are aligned with your team and it is readable

Comment: If your purpose is to make sure that your code conforms with standard code style, then how about using [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8) package to automatically format your source code according to [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008) Python style guide, and let that decide?

It will likely not format text inside your comment blocks but your code at least will stay automatically style-conformant.

Comment: @Olli I'm pretty sure `#` comment indentation isn't part of PEP, which is why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: @Kache: There'd be too many issues with indentation in commented-out code for a linter rule to be practical.